# Python Keras ImageDataGenerator: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init'

Tags: python, inheritance, keras, super

I am trying to write a data generator, and I would like to inherit the ImageDataGenerator object from Keras. The intention is to use some of the image preprocessing capabilities of the Keras module in my own generator

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Unfortunately I am still trying to understand how the super classes work and the inheritance thing, so I'm having a hard time debugging my code.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

class dataGenerator(ImageDataGenerator):
    """
    A data generator object that flows data from selected source.
    Initializes with parameters from Keras ImageDataGenerator.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(dataGenerator, self).init(*args, **kwargs)
        self.iterator=None
```

When I try to create an object I get the following error:

```
d = dataGenerator()

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-44bd98315a72>", line 1, in <module>
    d = dataGenerator()

  File "C:/Users/joshu/Documents/Code/Self Driving Car/data_utils.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(dataGenerator, self).init(*args, **kwargs)

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init'
```

I am referencing a code sample from mratsim on GitHub:

[1]https://github.com/mratsim/Amazon_Forest_Computer_Vision/blob/master/src/k_dataloader.py

where he inherits the same object. I'm guessing it worked for him..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__init__` method must have the 4 underscores, just like you did in the `def` part of it.

This is a Python pattern, and the parent class also follows this:

```
super(dataGenerator,self).__init__(...)
```

---

Off topic: often, class names begin with capitalized letters, to distinguish them from ordinary value vars. So, `DataGenerator` would be a better name following that recommendation.

Comment: Ah I'm an idiot, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks! Okay good advice I'll go with that nomenclature.

Answer (score -1):

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

class dataGenerator(ImageDataGenerator):
    """
    A data generator object that flows data from selected source.
    Initializes with parameters from Keras ImageDataGenerator.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ImageDataGenerator.__init__(self,*args, **kwargs)
        self.iterator=None
```

super() works in python 3.x .Probably you are using python 2.x

Comment: super() is used in python 2 as well (though a less verbose version is supported in python 3).  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super vs https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: oh thanx ,few days ago  I encountered the same problem and I searched alot about super but I wasn't able to find it out.So I came with above version